# Inserting into SQL using an OpenXml

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, xml, sqlxml

Hi I am trying to insert data into an SQL Server Database using an XML file which has some data  as follows.I was able to do the attribute mapping in OPENXML.If i try to pass the XML as elements instead of attributes i get an error regarding the null insertion.

Following is my XML FILE (containg attributes)

```
<NewDataSet>
  <SampleDataTable id="20" Name="as" Address="aaa" Email="aa" Mobile="123" />
</NewDataSet>
```

I am successful using the above format.If i use the below format i face errors

```
<Customer>
  <Id>20</Id>
  <Name>Cn</Name>
  <Address>Pa</Address>
  <Email>bnso@gmail.com</Email>
  <Mobile>12345513213</Mobile>
</Customer>
```

This is my openXML in SQL

```
 insert into @tempTable
    select * from openxml (@xmlHandle,'ROOT/Customer/',1)
    with (Cust_id int '@id',
          Customer_Name varchar(30) '@Name',
          Address varchar(30) '@Address',
          Email_id varchar(30) '@Email',
          Mobile_no bigint '@Mobile'
          )

    Insert into Test.dbo.tblCustomers (Cust_id,Customer_Name,Address,Email,Mobile_No) (select * from @tempTable)
```

please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you're trying to fetch data as attributes, but int your xml data is inside elements. Try this:

```
insert into @tempTable
select *
from openxml (@xmlHandle,'ROOT/Customer/',1)
with (Cust_id int '@id',
      Customer_Name varchar(30) 'Name[1]',
      Address varchar(30) 'Address[1]',
      Email_id varchar(30) 'Email[1]',
      Mobile_no bigint 'Mobile[1]'
      )
```

Or you can do this without openxml:

```
select
    t.c.value('Name[1]', 'varchar(30)') as Name,
    t.c.value('Address[1]', 'varchar(30)') as Address,
    t.c.value('Email[1]', 'varchar(30)') as Email,
    t.c.value('Mobile[1]', 'bigint') as Mobile
from @Data.nodes('Customer') as t(c)
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/22269)</kbd>**

Comment: Thanks for ur reply.. I'm Having more than 1 customer details, how can i proceed

Answer (score 1):

The problem is "element value" vs "element attribute".

This page has good examples of both:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187897%28v=sql.90%29.aspx

```
<Customer>   
   <CustomerID>LILAS</CustomerID>
   <ContactName>Carlos Gonzlez</ContactName>
   <Order OrderID="10283" CustomerID="LILAS" EmployeeID="3" OrderDate="1996-08-16T00:00:00">
      <OrderDetail ProductID="72" Quantity="3"/>
   </Order>
</Customer>
</ROOT>'

-- Create an internal representation of the XML document.
EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @XmlDocumentHandle OUTPUT, @XmlDocument

-- Execute a SELECT statement using OPENXML rowset provider.
SELECT    *
FROM      OPENXML (@XmlDocumentHandle, '/ROOT/Customer',2)
           WITH (CustomerID  varchar(10),
                 ContactName varchar(20))
EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @XmlDocumentHandle
```